# How to extend a window over display/workspace in Yosemite

Tags: macos, window-manager

Is there a way to extend a window over one display in OS X Yosemite, i.e. to make it larger than one display?

Answer (score 1):

System Preferences -> Mission Control -> Untick "Displays have separate Spaces" and restart.

[image]

After restart, you will be able to have 1 window expand over 2 displays.

Answer (score 0):

Only manually.
Alt/click the green dot, top left, which ought to fill the screen at least top to bottom, then grab the right edge & drag across.

Alternatively, grabbing the bottom right corner will let you do it in one move,  but without aligning the left edge.